# $_GET variables empty .htaccess rewrite

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

Given the URL

```
https://example.com/api/test/512/31
```

I want to rewrite to:

```
https://example.com/api/test.php?param1=512&param2=31
```

I've tried:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php?param1=$1&param2=$2 [QSA,L]
```

The rewrite works but `$1` and `$2` are empty. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php?param1=$1&param2=$2 [QSA,L]
> ```

How do you think `$1` and `$2` get set? You've not created any capturing groups in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (which is a negated pattern so can't "match" anything anyway), so the `$1` and `$2` *backreferences* will indeed always be empty.

Since you are using extensionless URLs that map directly to files you also need to make sure that MultiViews is disabled (if not already). If MultiViews is enabled then you'd get the same result - no URL parameters - since mod_negotiation would have issued an internal subrequest for the file before mod_rewrite.

**UPDATE:**

Criteria (from comments):

- Your `.htaccess` file is in the `/api` subdirectory.
- `/api/<something>` always maps to `/api/<something>.php`. `<something>` can consist of an arbitrary number of path segments, eg. `different/anothersubfolder/filename`.
- The `/512/31` path segments at the end of the URL can consist of digits and letters. There are always two path segments, ie. `/#1/#2`.

Try the following instead:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/api/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(\w+)/(\w+)$ $1.php?param1=$2&param2=$3 [QSA,L]
```

The shorthand character class `\w` matches `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` and `_` (underscore). So that covers the "numbers and letters".

Comment: Some extra information that I should have put in the question: My htaccess is 1 directory below my www root (I have a different htaccess in root that I don't want to use for this subfolder).

Comment: I want to be able to pass both numbers and strings as parameters.

Comment: Also, I want this htaccess to work even when drilling down multiple directories. For instance with the URL: https://example.com/api/different/anothersubfolder/filename/512/31

Comment: By "1 directory below", I assume it's at `/api/.htaccess`. "both numbers and strings" - By "strings", I assume you mean _letters_? I've updated my answer.

Comment: My mistake. My htaccess is directly inside of the api directory. What I meant to say is that my api folder is 1 directory below my www root (in case that matters).

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought - and that's the criteria I've used in my updated answer.